# What to put in Business Logic Layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I have read lots of articles and they seem to vary from one author/developer to the next. In my situation, I am thinking about this setup for testing a project:

1. Presentation Layer via ASP.NET MVC
2. Service Layer (my plan is ASP.NET MVC Web API; this is on separate assembly)
3. Business Logic Layer
4. DAL using EF

Some articles said I should not put CRUD operations on BLL and BLL should only contain business logic. Also, some said BLL should not access DAL. But what if a business logic needs data stored in DB to calculate/work on logic? I guess my questions would be:

1. If BLL shouldn't access DAL, how about those business logic that needs data in DB for it to be able to perform the logic?
2. BLL are entities, right? Are they the same as POCO or would I still have POCO in DAL?
3. Also, is DBContext in BLL? Some say it should so I'm confused.
4. What about the no CRUD in BLL? Should I do that?
5. Repository interface is in DAL?

Any additional comments/suggestions/information on what my planned setup would be very welcome (even if it is not related to BLL).

Comment: The `BLL should not access DAL` article should be quite interesting. Unless they mean a DAL abstraction is injected into the BLL, rather than BLL coupling directly to it.

Comment: @StuartLC - OK, I somewhat agree with BLL not accessing DAL, but what if you need some data in DB to perform some logic? For example, only apply discount if customer has this much number of orders for the last 10 years. How do I get that data?

Comment: @g_b StuartLC's point was exactly that this strict separation is hard to maintain, perhaps even impossible.

Comment: @BCdotNET - Reading again, yeah, somehow I missed that

Comment: WRT your question, check out http://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/what-is-a-business-logic-layer-anyway/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581779.aspx and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223034/dal-vs-bll-functions-return-types and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/mvc-layered-project-structure etc.

Comment: Hmm... Are the articles you read saying only your presentation layer should access your DAL and then pass on the data to the BLL to process? i.e. have the view as the coordinator? If so, I wouldn't recommend it. What you have to keep in mind is that doing BL without the underlying data in most applications does not make sense. BL's purpose is generally to make sense of your raw data and do things with it which it can't do without having means to fetch it. If they're saying your view should pass on this data to the BLL, it would work but would not be the best solution.

Comment: Apologies, yes - business logic (with the exception of trivial validation) invariably needs access to a lot of information about the state of whatever it is trying to 'police' - this information generally comes from DAL or Repository, so it is hard to imagine a BLL situation without a dependency at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on a project some time ago.

Our project arquitecture ressembled to what you suggest.

We had an ASP.NET MVC site, which accessed a WEB API (in an external solution).

The WEB API also referenced an external solution entirely made up of static libraries, which contained the data layer (just entities) and the persistence layer.

We also had ***Data Transfer Objects*** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx)) for communication between the web service and the clients, and to decouple the entities entirely from external solutions.

We had the business logic in the WEB API project. We would create, manipulate and store the entities from within the WEB API HTTP methods.

But we didn't accessed the data and persistence layer directly, we had an intermediate layer, we called it entities manager. These managers would be injected on our WEB API controllers (We used [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html) for *Dependency Injection*) and would handle the creation of the entity, and also the persistence, so we'd decouple everything.

This approach worked very well for us, and we made a pretty well maintainable and scalable project.

I hope it may be of help for you, and of course, there probably exist better techniques.

**PS:**

We used an IRepository interface provided to us by the entites manager to persist the entities. This was our only access to the persistence layer. Inner logic, such as persistence strategies (like EF's DbContext, or File IO) would be internal to the persistence project.

---

This is an example of our bussiness logic in one of our WEB API HTTP methods:

```
// "repository" is an IRepository<Entity>
entityManager.Transaction( (repository) => {
     Entity ourEntity = repository.CreateNew();

     //Manipulate the entity somehow

     repository.Add(ourEntity);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The data will take different forms, for example in the data storage **DS** (SQL Server for example) they are on relational tables, in the data access layer **DAL** they are in the Data Model (object model) like Entity Framework **EF**, in the presentation layer **PL** they would be in View Model, and on the HTML page or desktop form they will live inside a **UI** component.

At a single point when a layer calls another layer they have to have a communication channel and a data container that would change the data from one form to another.

Whenever a **DAL** asks for some data from **DS** it should be changed from table form to a object model form, so the **DAL** does not care about the table form. When you send the data back from the **DAL** to the **PL** it should be changed to be in a View Model form and again the **PL** does not care about the object model form, and so on.

You might ask about the **BLL** layer, I guess this layer most of the time is just a delegate in the middle when there is no logic in the middle, so for some performance matters the **PL** would access the **DAL** directly.

I hope this would answer your questions.

**EDIT**

For the **BLL** you consider as the mind of the system, the **PL** is just showing what it receives, and **DAL** just returned what is asked for to return by acquiring the right **DS** entities. So the CRUD would be in the **DAL**.

For Example you need to search for a list of employees, the **BLL** here is just a delegate layer where it delegates the **PL** call to the **DAL** and return back the results. But in case of adding a new employee, the **BLL** would have an interface with function like **AddNewEmoloyee** which will do some business logic functions like for example making sure that the salary is according to the employee level range, and then it  will call the needed **CRUD** actions in the **DAL**.